# How to return a document from MongoDB with given fields lowercased?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, data-conversion

I am using the Mongo extension of PHP.

I have a collection of two-level documents in MongoDB, and each document has a "email" field *at a second level* (i. e., "user_data.email" field). I want to get a `MongoCursor` loaded with documents, each having this field *in lowercase*. Is this possible?

The dataset is ~100000 documents and I have already profiled my application and know that `strtolower()` over the results at PHP side is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a pain that. maybe [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/)?

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit( this._id, values: {
            email: this.user_data.email.toLowerCase(),
            other: this.other_field.toLowerCase()
        });
    },
    function(){},
    {
        "out": { "replace": "newCollection" }
    }
)
```

And the get the results from the new collection with `.find()`.

Or you could wait for 2.6, where [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/aggregate/) **does** return a cursor

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "email": { "$toLower": "$user_data.email" } } }
])
```

Really not sure of your use case. E-mail **should** be considered case insensitive, so any matching should take that into consideration.

But if comparison is your thing, why not use [strcasecomp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp) ?

At the end of the day, this is probably something that you **should** update in your data, and then make sure that **new** records are always inserted with the email address in lowercase.

Comment: Yeah, thought about the MapReduce already, but problem is, I'll probably need more than email field from that document. :-/

Comment: And for the use case - we compare emails from MongoDB with emails from other data source. So, PHP does comparison, and I am trying to reduce the load on this.

Comment: @hijarian That's easy. Just emit a "document" as the value. Do you need the example?

Comment: @hijarian and for **comparison** there is a function for that. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Well... the comparison part is another question, really... :) To be short, in the end I need the list of emails from the MongoDB filtered by the list of emails from MySQL. Trying to evade the n^2 algorithms, I load all of the values from MySQL data as keys of PHP array and do a comparison afterwards by using `array_key_exists`. And it's case-sensitive for sure. Problem is, emails in MongoDB and MySQL _are_ in different cases.

Comment: @hijarian What is not in the answer that explains this? I reference the PHP function you can use if this is what you need. Please **re-read**. Can you "project" case from find()? No. Do I show ways this can be done? Yes. Could you also project case from MySQL? Yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49521/discussion-between-hijarian-and-neil-lunn)